# Double contractions

Tags: contractions

Natives, what's the PDE grammar around double contractions like "**couldn't've**", "**mustn't've**" "**shouldn't've**" or "**needn't've**"? Are they in use in formal or informal English and in spoken or written English and can we non-natives use them?

Comment: They might be spoken like that, but are written as **couldn't have** etc. However in PDE we increasingly see (on forums and social media) **couldn't of** which is phonetic but strictly ungrammatical.

Comment: You might be interested in [this answer](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/3267/240807) to the similar English StackExchange question *Can a word be contracted twice?*

Comment: They are in use and I have seen them used.  I would not say they are ungrammatical as I can't think of any rule they break.  My favorite example is "ya'll'll"  for "you all will".

Comment: Such spellings (couldn't've) are relatively rare.  Such pronunciation, on the other hand, is common.

Comment: I agree with @Tᴚoɯɐuo and couldn't have said it any better. Are they in use? That depends on what you mean by "in use" – you'll hear them relatively frequently, but see them [in print] only on very rare occasions.

Comment: @J.R. By saying **in use** I mean informal and formal English and spoken and written English. I'll edit the question.

Comment: See https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/209806/26526 for some discussion on this topic.

Answer (score 2):

They are used in spoken English and can be used in writing too, although this is not common.

This can be seen in the [BBC English course](http://www.bbc.co.uk/learningenglish/course/intermediate/unit-6/session-4/activity-3) and also in [Wiktionary](https://en.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/Category:English_double_contractions).